# Dozer mapping is vs get

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

In the following case:

```
public class Race {
    private Status finished;

    public Status getFinished() {
        return finsihed;
    }

    public void setFinished(Status finished) {
        this.finsihed = finished;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished == Status.FINISHED;
    }
}

public class RaceDTO {
    private Status finished;

    public Status getFinished() {
        return finsihed;
    }

    public void setFinished(Status finished) {
        this.finsihed = finished;
    }
}
```

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) is mapping a RaceDTO class with `isFinished()` method rather than `getFinished()`. Why is that and how to cope with it? I prefer to use annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If return type is boolean "is" prefix is used instead of "get"

Answer (score 0):

isFinished is a common way to indicate a boolean return type.

```
if ( race.isFinished() ) {}
```

vs

```
if ( race.getFinished() ) {}
```

the first is abit more clear

Answer (score 0):

According to section "*8.3 Design Patterns for Properties*" of [JavaBens specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/), boolean properties may have a "*is*" acccess method. If has one, this method will be preferential over the "*get*" if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I have to add annotation over a field, and then neither method is invoked

```
public class Race {
    @Mapping("finished")
    private Status finished;

    public Status getFinished() {
        return finsihed;
    }

    public void setFinished(Status finished) {
        this.finsihed = finished;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished == Status.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... that was not actually asked. But I'm glad you managed to solve  your problem.